# How to select specific items in Include in EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an entity that looks like this:

```
public class UserOrganization
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public MyUser User { get; set; }

    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrganizationId")]
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
}
```

The above entity is used to provide a many-to-many relationship between `MyUser` and `Organization` entities. Now, when I  want to get data from my repository for a user I also want to include data for an organization, and I have something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<MyUser> GetFullUsers()
{
    return _context.Users
                   .Include(u => u.Location)
                   .Include("UserOrganizations.Organization")
                   // And many other include statements removed for breivty.
                   .ToList();
}
```

Now, this works all fine and I get the relevant data, but for `"UserOrganizations.Organization"` I get a lot of nested data. What I mean is that my `Organization` entity includes members, which are of type `MyUser`, and then it shows the users, and afterward again the organizations of the users and so on because everything is deeply nested. So, basically I don't want to get the other data, and I want to select just a few properties from `.Include("UserOrganizations.Organization")`. How can I achieve this?

Please note that I do not want to write the whole query as a select statement because I have a lot of other stuff that gets fetched which I removed for brevity so manually mapping stuff would be cumbersome. I just need to make sure that `.Include("UserOrganizations.Organization")` does not retrieve also the nested data or if I can just select which properties from `Organization` to retrieve here?

**EDIT:**

I already have the following inside `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserOrganization>(uo =>
{
    uo.HasKey(k => new { k.UserId, k.OrganizationId });

    uo.HasOne(u => u.User)
      .WithMany(o => o.UserOrganizations)
      .HasForeignKey(k => k.UserId);

    uo.HasOne(o => o.Organization)
      .WithMany(u => u.UserOrganizations)
      .HasForeignKey(k => k.OrganizationId);
});
```

And my `MyUser` and `Organization` entities have the following properties:

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser
{
     // Rest removed for brevity
     public ICollection<UserOrganization> UserOrganizations { get; set; } = new List<UserOrganization>();
}
```

And

```
public class Organization
{
    // Rest removed for brevity
    public ICollection<UserOrganization> UserOrganizations { get; set; } = new List<UserOrganization>();
}
```

Comment: Looks like Lazy Loading is off in EF Core by default so I guess this is not your issue. I am not sure what is happening then.

Comment: I believe you have to do with via Fluent API with reference this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many  I don't believe that attributes are enough

Comment: @mvermef I already have it. Check my edited question.

Comment: @AllenR Yes, it is disabled by default in EF Core, I read that too.

Comment: There have been many similar questions and the answer is always: can't be done (that's probably why people keep asking). EF performs relationship fixup, so it populates navigation properties with everything that's available in the context's cache. If there are circular references (which are very common in a persistence model), yes you'll have reference loops. No other alternative than to query exactly what you need into view models or DTOs. BTW, seems you missed the `ThenInclude`method.

Comment: I just looking over other similar questions, @GertArnold is right... its just not possible at present state of the framework.